# Intersection between different shapes

Tags: c++, inheritance, geometry, polymorphism, virtual

I am trying to make a library of shapes. There is the following class Shape, with this declaration:

```
#include "pos.h"
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H

class Shape{
protected:
    Pos pos;
public:
    Pos getPos();
    void setPos(Pos pos);
    virtual bool intersection(Shape&);

    Shape():pos((Pos){0,0}){}
    Shape(Pos pos):pos(pos){}
    Shape(int x, int y):pos((Pos){x,y}){}
};

#endif      /*  SHAPE_H */
```

As you can see there is a virtual function member(intersection). This function is intended to compute whether two shapes intersect(no mater if they are circles, rectangles or whatever).
I have also declared these classes(Circle and Rectangle):

```
#include "pos.h"
#include "shape.h"

#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
class Rectangle;
#endif      /*  RECTANGLE_H */

#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H

class Circle : public Shape{
private:
    int radius;
public:
    int getRadius(){return radius;}
    void setRadius(int radius){this->radius=radius;}

    bool containsPos(Pos p);
    bool intersection(Circle& c);
    bool intersection(Rectangle& r);

    Circle();
    Circle(Pos pos);
    Circle(int radius);
    Circle(Pos pos, int radius);
};

#endif      /*  CIRCLE_H    */
```

---

```
#include "pos.h"
#include "shape.h"

#ifndef CIRCLE_H
class Circle;
#endif      /*  CIRCLE_H */

#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H

class Rectangle : public Shape{
private:
    int width;
    int height;
public:
    int getWidth(){return width;}
    int getHeight(){return height;}

    void setWidth(int width){this->width=width;}
    void setHeight(int height){this->height=height;}

    bool containsPos(Pos pos);
    bool intersection(Rectangle& r);
    bool intersection(Circle& c);

    Rectangle():Shape(),width(0),height(0){}
    Rectangle(int w, int h):Shape(),width(w),height(h){}
    Rectangle(Pos p, int w, int h):Shape(p), width(w),height(h){}
    Rectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h):Shape(x,y), width(w), height(h){}

};

#endif      /*  RECTANGLE_H */
```

As you can see, I have made a member function in each subclass of Shape for each other subclass of Shape.
It seems good but there is a problem. When you call intersection giving a Shape(I mean that the compiler doesn't know the Shape it is, for example when taken from a vector of Shapes) as a parameter it doesn't work(g++:no matching function for call).
I guess it is because I am not overiding the virtual function of Shape because as long as the parameters are different the functions are different(I think).
Well, I wonder if there is a cool way to achieve this goal.

EDIT: I have found more stuff to my question in the 11th chapter of Modern c++ design. It is about multimethods(methods with arguments whose type has to be checked at runtime).
In the section 9 of this chapter the author mention that dynamic_cast is a good option when convined with static_cast. If I find more about this I will edit again.

EDIT 2: in chapter 11 of "Modern c++ design" you can find in section two that the author mentions that collision detection between different shapes in games is a typical problem where the use of multimethods becomes needed. I didn't say but this small library was intended to be for a game, so it is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable [run time type information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information), create an intersection method which actually takes a Shape class and use dynamic_cast to find out which object you got, then call the overloaded intersection call on the derived objects.

Note though that RTTI can seriously slow down your code, and having a special function for each type of shape seriously hinders the flexibility and maintainability of your code. A generalized solution like Richard proposes is likely more beneficial in the long run.

Comment: I think that it is I was looking for. I don't understand why that is slower than what Richard proposed. If you have a vector of Shapes and you call a virtual member function it is also doing a casting to the specific Shape it but implicitly. I think. Thanks!

Comment: No, RTTI and virtual functions are very different. For RTTI the program will be instrumented with a lot of additional code to be able to know at run time what type each object is. Virtual functions work completely differently, a virtual function is addressed via a vtable which you can think of as simply an array of pointers to methods. In effect a virtual function is only a single indirection by a pointer, the RTTI solution gives you much more overhead. This might not matter for something you do incidentally, but for code that you call a lot, which this likely is, it matters a hell of a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The design is wrong.  First Shape needs a virtual method named `BoundingRect` that returns Top, Left, Bottom, Right of the area that the derived class fill. Then the first thing Shape.intersection does is to determine if bounding rectangles intersect; a trivial exercise.

Now it gets harder.  Each shape must provide a virtual name `Paths`, which returns a list/array of line segments/bezier curves that **truely** describes the area.  The `intersection` method then determines if any path in either shape intersects.

Good luck.

Comment: The goal of the problem is not to compute any area is to compute IF intersects. Anyway the implementation of intersection() for Rectangle and Circle is already done. My question is about how can I make to have a fuction intersection that accepts any type of Shape as a parameter. From the second part of your answer, using for example a vector for the task could be a good way but I wonder if there is an  other way for getting ONLY one Shape as the input. Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't need to compute the area, you only have to look at whether the bounding paths intersect.

Comment: Checking the area is an optimization!  Its much faster then checking that the paths intersection

Comment: For example checking if two circles intersect is as easy as to check if the distance between centers is lower than the addition of radius. Or even faster if the distance beetween centers squared is lower than the addition of radius squared they intersect.

Comment: Well, anyway I realy like the idea of having a a function that accepts a vector. I think I will include both a function for a vector and a function getting a genneric Shape like @wich suggested.Thanks!

Comment: @RichardSchneider You say checking the area is an optimization, can you elaborate on that? How would you characterize the area? If we generalize to triangulated simple polygons then O(faces) == O(edges) or do you restrict to regular convex shapes?

Comment: @wich, as a fast check each shape should have bounding rectangle. Checking intersection of paths/vectors is usually much slower.  And most of the time shapes will not intersect.

Comment: @Ah you mean that, I was only talking about the actual interaction check, not the culling by bounding boxes/spheres. So there is still no computation of area, which is what the OP was referring to.